# How to encrypt a Huge query string to in short

Tags: asp.net, encryption, query-string

I have a huge query string which is around 6000 to 7000 characters, is it possible to encrpyt the string in short?

any alogrithms ?

Usign ASP.NET as the web app.

Comment: do you really need to put that much information into a query string?

Comment: Some browsers limit the URL to about 2 kB. You should keep the query string well below that to be safe.

Comment: Avoid to do it. The answer on how to compress it - if can be compress, is to gZip it.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is don't do it - it probably indicates you are doing something wrong.

If you have to then I would say the best way would be to store the long query string in a database field and generate a Guid you can store as a key against it.

You can then pass the Guid in the query string and when the page loads you can then retrieve the full details from the database using the key.

Answer (score 0):

The URL accepts 255 character, after that you'll get nothing.

Use what Mr. Kevin mentioned, database storage, or use the context session to store variables you are sending in the query string.